# Wide swing cascode current mirror

Tags: current-mirror

This is a high swing cascode current mirror. My question is what is the significance of the connection from the drain of M3 to the gate of M1 and M2? What would happen if both M3 and M1 were diode connected MOSFETs?

[image]

Comment: @Nino Indeed the same circuit, however there's no cascode voltage at the gate of M3 and M4 in that schematic. Since that voltage is essential, that circuit is not going to work like that.

Comment: That is a bad schematic you can't tell what is connected to what

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's not shown in the schematic, but it's indeed there. Check the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*what is the significance of the connection from the drain of M3 to the gate of M1 and M2?*

That connection is part of the feedback loop which sets the Vgs of M1 and M2.
If M1 (and also M2) have an Id > Iref, the voltage at the drain of M3 drops.
This decreases the Vgs of M1 (and also M2) restoring the balance Id_M1 = Iref

*What would happen if both M3 and M1 were diode connected MOSFETs?*

Then the circuit becomes quite different. M5 would not serve a purpose anymore. The circuit would become a simple cascoded mirror. The minimum voltage at the drain of M4 needed for the correct output current would also rise. That is one of the things this circuit improves.

Comment: Here Vds of M1 and M2 and Vds of M3 and M4 will be the same or different??

Comment: You will learn nothing if I just told you so I'm not going to answer that until you say what you think is the case and why. So what are your thoughts on this ? Hints: all 4 transistors have the same size. Do all of them have the same Id ? Is Vds that important anyway ?